# Rails 3 and fields_for with activemodel (tableless) object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a tableless model that I'm trying to generate some form fields for.

The form looks like so:

```
= form_for :users, url: users_path do |f|
  - books.each do |book|
    = f.fields_for :books, book do |bf|
      = bf.hidden_field :title, value: book.title
  = f.submit "Send"
```

What I'm expecting to be generated for each field is something like this:

```
<input name="users[books][][title]" type="hidden" value="Some Book Title">
<input name="users[books][][title]" type="hidden" value="Some Book Title">
<input name="users[books][][title]" type="hidden" value="Some Book Title">
```

However, what I'm actually getting is

```
<input name="users[books][title]" type="hidden" value="Some Book Title">
<input name="users[books][title]" type="hidden" value="Some Book Title">
<input name="users[books][title]" type="hidden" value="Some Book Title">
```

Which means when the form is submitted only the last input field is available as the previous two have been overwritten due to them referencing the same thing.

This works ok when the model has an active record backend but not when it's tableless.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

I think you need to add this to your users model

```
def books_attributes= attributes
  # do something with attributes
  # probably:
  # self.books = attributes.map{|k,v|Book.new(v)}
end
```

And also define `persisted?` method for Book instance. Make it just to return `false`.

And add `f` for your `fields_for` in view:

```
= f.fields_for :books, book do |bf|
```

I hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Welldan97 brings up a very important point. You need the persisted? method. I was getting an undefined method for the model name earlier. Check my gist out. It works, but not perfect by any means. https://gist.github.com/2638002

Answer (score 0):

Right now this is pretty hard to do with Rails 3.x. That will change with Rails 4 with the advent of `ActiveModel::Model` which will give all the base methods for your model to be `ActionPack` compatable.

However until Rails 4 is released a good standard to make your model `ActionPack` compatible is the `ActionModel::Model` module itself. It "should" work with the current stable Rails. [Check it out](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/model.rb)

How you choose to implement this is your decision, but I would probably just download the file and throw it in my application's `lib` directory. That way I could just include it using

```
class Book
  include ActiveModel::Model
end
```

Easy Rails Form compatibility for custom models.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f.fields_for 'books[]', book do |bf|
```